# How to include eclipselink dependency in maven project

Tags: maven, eclipselink

I have following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and the library is there on repo : http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.5.2/

but eclipse is unable to download the library. Eclipselink version 2.5.0 is getting downloaded successfully, what is the problem with 2.5.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.5.2 is fairly new. Perhaps it hasn't made it around to all of the mirrors, or something went wrong when it was published to maven central? Does 2.5.1 work for you?

Comment: 2.5.2 is now getting downloaded successfully.